# Adding a root bone and parenting after animating, weird glitch effect

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, parent

I'll explain the problem and process briefly. Blend file at the bottom if anyone wishes to have a go themselves.

I created a mesh with lots of **tails/arms** (See image below), created an **armature** with separated bone structures (but are part of the same Armature), **CTRl+P with automatic weights** to the mesh and **animated** each one using a **Disconnected IK bone**. Looks like this:

[image: Animation Gif]

To import happily into UE4, I have to **create a root bone** and **parent (Keep Offset)** the **IK bones** on the ends and **Start bones** for each arm to the root bone as demonstrated below. For each IK and start bone I **unchecked the inherit rotation, and scale** checkbox as well. See below:

[image: Pareting]

[image: Relations]

Unfortunately it creates this **weird glitch effect** in the animation which also shows up in UE4 after exporting, again please see below:

*As a note the Root Bone also seems to move in the animation as if it's inheriting rotations from some bones or something.*

[image: Glitch effect]

And here's the hierarchy just for shits and giggles :P

[image]

I hope someone can help, appreciate the time, cheers.

[image]

Comment: You have at least one bone (Bone_Tip_03) which has a chain length of 0.  That means it involves all bones, including your new root, changing your animation.  Check and fix all chain lengths.

Comment: I believe that IK_03, IK_05, and IK_13 are the culprits, as @Nathan pointed out, they all have chain length of 0 instead of 3.

Comment: Perfect you guys are absolutely right, they were the culprits. Nice spot!
@Nathan if you want to put that in an answer I will happily mark is as the final answer